# If view is child, it doesn't work properly

Tags: ember.js

Very simple template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="win-edit-foot">
    {{name}}
</script>
```

ContainerView class:

```
App.WinElementEditView = Em.ContainerView.extend({
    classNames:['edit'],
    childViews:['foot'],
    foot:Em.View.extend({
        templateName:'win-edit-foot',
        name:'some name'
    })
});
```

It doesn't work, {{name}} in template replaced with "" (nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your template. If you want the `name` property of the view, you have to replace `{{name}}` with `{{view.name}}`, according to [View context changes](https://gist.github.com/2494968).

I suggest you to take a look at the [Understanding the Ember.js view layer guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/view_layer/).

Here is the JSFiddle which does not work: [view `{{name}}`, and the JSFiddle which works [with `{{view.name}}`](http://jsfiddle.net/xj8nK/).